# SELECT rows with primary key of multiple columns

Tags: node.js, postgresql

How do I select all relevant records according to the provided list of pairs?

**table:**

```sql
CREATE TABLE "users_groups" (
    "user_id" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "group_id" BIGINT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, group_id),
    "permissions" VARCHAR(255)
);
```

For example, if I have the following JavaScript `array` of pairs that I should get from DB

```
[
  {user_id: 1, group_id: 19},
  {user_id: 1, group_id: 11},
  {user_id: 5, group_id: 19}
]
```

Here we see that the same `user_id` can be in multiple groups.

I can pass with `for-loop` over every array element and create the following **query**:

```sql
SELECT * FROM users_groups
    WHERE (user_id = 1 AND group_id = 19) 
    OR (user_id = 1 AND group_id = 11) 
    OR (user_id = 5 AND group_id = 19);
```

But is this the best solution? Let say if the array is very long. As I know query length may get **~1GB**.

what is the best and quick solution to do this?

Comment: If your list is sufficiently long it is generally best practice to pop those values into a temporary table and then JOIN on that table in your SQL. Depending on your RDBMS you may find that stacking a large UNION query performs better than a bunch of OR's in your WHERE clause too. You may get more precise answers if you let us know which RDBMS you are using (you have tagged both Postgres and mysql which are different products).

Comment: What do you mean by "to pop those values", can you please clarify your answer with an example?

Comment: If you are getting the arrray of user_id, group_id pairs from the database, why make another call to the db?  Can you get the permissions at the same time?

Comment: What I mean is to 1) Create a temporary table in your database 2) load your really huge list into it 3) Query by joining your existing table to the temp table to retrieve your results. You won't have a choice after your SQL goes over your `max_allowed_packet` size in mysql anyway, but I would definitely switch to this method WELL before you get anywhere close to SQL of that size. The other options explored in the comments and answers here (as well as your questions) will suffice for smaller lists, but you are talking about 1gb sized SQL strings, which is WAY too big for a sql string.

Comment: @Jeremy I do not get this array of pairs from the database, to be honest, in the end, I have to overwrite the existing ones and insert the missing ones. This is the cache that I want to synchronize with the database. But the first step is to get all the records, dividing the local ones into existing ones and those that do not exist in the database. And then, separately, rewriting those that exist and adding those that do not exist. I think this can somehow be done in one query?

Comment: @Pumych: if you "*have to overwrite the existing ones and insert the missing ones*" then why are you using a SELECT statement? An `insert .. on conflict` (without any SELECT before) would be way more efficient

Comment: @JNevill If I understand right Postgres do not have like 'max_allowed_packet' limit (https://www.postgresql-archive.org/max-allowed-packet-equivalent-in-Postgres-td1921557.html)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm not sure how to do that ```insert into users_groups( user_id, group_id, permissions) values ( (1,19,1),(1,11,1),(5,19,1) ) on conflict (user_id, group_id) update set permissions = ???;```

Comment: Pretty much, yes: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=15d9ce03bedfcecda3e8b2d2287a6340 (btw: there is no performance or storage advantage when limiting a varchar column to 255)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks for this perfect example. Can you please add a small explanation about the ```... do update set permissions = excluded.permissions ...``` I just can't find any information about it.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205340/discussion-between-pumych-and-a-horse-with-no-name).

Answer (score 2):

Bill Karwin's answer will work for Postgres just as well.

However, I have made the experience that joining against a VALUES clause is very often faster than a large IN list (with hundreds if not thousands of elements):

```
select ug.*
from user_groups ug
  join ( 
     values (1,19), (1,11), (5,19), ... 
  ) as l(uid, guid) on l.uid = ug.user_id and l.guid = ug.group_id;
```

This assumes that there are no duplicates in the values provided, otherwise the JOIN would result in duplicated rows, which the IN solution would not do.

Comment: Just to clarify  ((1,2), (1,2)) this is a duplicate right?

Comment: @Pumych yes it is

Answer (score 1):

You tagged both mysql and postgresql, so I don't know which SQL database you're really using.

MySQL at least supports tuple comparisons:

```
SELECT * FROM users_groups WHERE (user_id, group_id) IN ((1,19), (1,11), (5,19), ...)
```

This kind of predicate can be optimized in MySQL 5.7 and later. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/range-optimization.html#row-constructor-range-optimization

I don't know whether PostgreSQL supports this type of predicate, or if it optimizes it.

Comment: I using PostgreS (removed the other tag) I thought that this should be the same solution for both Postgres and MySQL. Anyway it works on Postgres but as you say I'm not sure if this solution is the best practice for Postgres